# Find a running count of a column name in sybase

Tags: sql, count, sap-ase

My table has a column like
[image]

No i need to calculate a running count of the column value in other column like
[image]

I am not able to get it, tried count(column_name) but it's giving me length of a column. Any idea how to do it in Sybase (ASE)??

Comment: Can you show us the query which generated the output for your `Device_name` table?

Comment: It's simple like,
Select 
Column1,
Column2,
Device_name,
Column4
FROM DBO.TABLE_NAME

Comment: You want only a row number beside the device_name ? or you want a count?

Comment: yeah can say rownumber, but it should give the row number/ Count for distinct values only.

Comment: I think we are going to need some way of determining an order for the device names.

Comment: `select device_name, running_count=identity(10) into table_b from table_a`. Do a select from `table_b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Biegeleisen hinted at the problem - determining a sort order for the devices.

If you don't care about the order of the returned rows, you could use:

```
SELECT     a.Device_name,
           ( SELECT count(*) FROM Devices 
             WHERE Device_name <= a.Device_name) AS "Running Count"
FROM       Devices a 
ORDER BY   Device_name
```

This gives:

```
Device_name          Running Count
-------------------- -------------
Android                          1
Apple                            2
Blackberry                       3
Unix                             4
Windows                          5
```

If you have a column (eg. "ID") that determines the order of the devices, then you could use code like this:

```
SELECT     a.Device_name,
           ( SELECT count(*) FROM Devices 
             WHERE ID <= a.ID) AS "Running Count"
FROM       Devices a 
ORDER BY   Device_name
```

giving us the running count in the original order:

```
Device_name          Running Count
-------------------- -------------
Apple                            1
Blackberry                       2
Windows                          3
Android                          4
Unix                             5
```

Of course, the order in which you get the results is not guaranteed unless you use "order by".